# How to configure my.cnf in 5.6.17?

Tags: mysql, performance, linux, my.cnf

On production server(linux machine mysql 5.6.17), I tried to find my.cnf to change the system variables, but my.cnf was not in /etc/my.cnf location. It was in usr/ directory.
Also that file contains only comments like -

```
# Remove leading # and set to the amount of RAM for the most important data
# cache in MySQL. Start at 70% of total RAM for dedicated server, else 10%.
# innodb_buffer_pool_size = 128M
```

Please tell me where should I copy my.cnf and how I can change variables like -

```
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 200M
max_connections = 300
```

Answer (score -2):

mysql started with option --defaults-file=FILE  Use the specified defaults file

change config.file(my.cnf)

Comment: how to change config file, it contains only comment starts with #.